# how to get large record in java programming using result set

Tags: java, resultset

I have 8670 record in database but in application it showing only 4227 record using ResultSet object . Is any way to fetch large records from database using  resultset

Answer (score 1):

I dont think 8670 record is a huge record but yes if you are holding them in your program then it may be a memory issue. However you can consider if they can be processed "streamwise". So by this way you can use the information needed from each record, then discard the record before retrieving the next. So in my opion if you want to avoid memory issues, streaming is really good way to go.

Comment: In my 25 years of developing DB apps I do not think I have ever needed to process 8670 separate records.  Not the downvoter.